# Access a different table from multiple possible ones on MySQL based on another's table attribute

Tags: mysql, polymorphic-associations

I'm doing a personal database project on MySQL, where a user sells its vehicle and adds different information based on the vehicle type (electric, hybrid or combustion), and I need the 'vehicle' table to access one of multiple possible tables depending on the value to one of its attributes ('Tipo_comb' which means vehicle type), this is the script:

```
create table Vehiculo
(
    ID int not null,
    Año int,
    Tipo_comb int,
    Fotos blob,
    primary key(ID)
);

create table Combustion
(
    ID int not null,
    Motor varchar(15),
    kmgl int,
    primary key(ID)
);

create table Electrico
(
    ID int not null,
    Bateria varchar(15),
    Autonomia varchar(15),
    primary key(ID)
);

create table Hibrido
(
    ID int not null,
    Motor varchar (15),
    Bateria varchar(15),
    kmgl int,
    primary key (ID)
);
```

In the 'Tipo_comb' attribute in 'Vehicle' table, I specify wether the vehicle is hybrid, electric or combustion (works exclusively with gas), so the user will need to add different information based on this attribute (if it's electric you add battery type, autonomy, etc; and if it's combustion you add its enginge characteristics, types , etc.).

At first I thought of a foreign key, but of course you can't reference multiple tables with one fk. I've taken the hint it is with table realtionships but I'm still a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Vehiculo.*,
       CASE WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Combustion'
            THEN Combustion.Motor
            WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Hibrido'
            THEN Hibrido.Motor
            END AS Motor,
       CASE WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Combustion'
            THEN Combustion.kmgl
            WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Hibrido'
            THEN Hibrido.kmgl
            END AS kmgl,
       CASE WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Electrico'
            THEN Electrico.Bateria
            WHEN Tipo_comb = 'Hibrido'
            THEN Hibrido.Bateria
            END AS Bateria,
       CASE WHEN Tipo_comb IN ('Electrico')
            THEN Electrico.Autonomia 
            END AS Autonomia 
FROM Vehiculo
LEFT JOIN Combustion USING (id)
LEFT JOIN Electrico USING (id)
LEFT JOIN Hibrido USING (id)
```